# Heap dump - retained size cyclic references

Tags: jvm, out-of-memory, vaadin, heap-memory, eclipse-memory-analyzer

An old long-running application in prod ran out of memory. When analyzing the thread dump I navigate myself with retained size and looking for objects with a lot of retained size to understand what cause the memory issues (either a leak or too many objects from some process).

In this case, the memory leak report points to HashedSession from jetty. When reviewing the sessions, I can see that the session in-app contains objects in attributes which refer to the same session in cycle.

Now, the problem is that I can't determine what are the components that make of retained size (which sum to the total retained size), and where they are coming from. The biggest size in the session is the session itself and other attributes don't have almost anything.

```
Class Name                                                                          | Retained Heap
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HashedSession @ 0x77d47bf70                        |   201 414 144
|- _attributes java.util.HashMap @ 0x782c20250                                      |   201 414 056
|  |- table java.util.HashMap$Node[16] @ 0x78594db98                                |   201 414 008
|  |  |- [10] java.util.HashMap$Node @ 0x787047090                                  |   201 411 880
|  |  |  |- value com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.WebApplicationContext @ 0x784244740|   201 411 848
|  |  |  |  |- session org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HashedSession @ 0x77d47bf70 |   201 414 144
|  |  |  |  |- browser com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.WebBrowser @ 0x7832eeb68      |           400
|  |  |  |  |- applications java.util.HashSet @ 0x787a9e1a8                         |           192
|  |  |  |  |- applicationToAjaxAppMgrMap java.util.HashMap @ 0x783280118           |           160
|  |  |  |  |- listeners java.util.Collections$SynchronizedList @ 0x787a9e190       |           104
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I know I'm doing probably something stupid here, but I thought that by following the biggest retained sizes (or second biggest to skip the cycle) I would come to the the real villains of the issue. But I can't find any other retained set of objects with similar retained size to point me to the next suspicious object (other than the original retained size of the session).

Running on Java 8, HotSpot JVM

Answer (score 0):

Yeh, you followed a cyclical reference starting from `HashedSession @ 0x77d47bf70` back to `HashedSession @ 0x77d47bf70`. However, you didn't completely look through the _attributes HashMap. What else is in there?

Are you using the "List Objects -> Outgoing references" by right clicking on `HashedSession @ 0x77d47bf70` ?

Comment: Actually, in the map, there was more or less nothing else (I went through the other ones, but they were significantly smaller in size). Unfortunately, I changed the company, so I can't really continue where I left off. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Thanks for following up. I guess it was something inside that HashedSession then.